# Упростить подсчет суммы ряда

Tags: python, функции, математика, рекурсия, ряды

```
def fact(t):
  if t == 0:
    return 1
  else:
    return t * fact(t-1)


def fun(x):
    k = 0
    s = x
    final_sum = 0
    while abs(s) > e:
        k += 1
        s *= (-1)**k * x**k/fact(3*k)
        final_sum += s
    return final_sum
```

факториал задавал сам, ибо нельзя использовать функцию из библиотеки math

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону [Рекуррентная формула](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0)

Comment: Если посчитал 5!, Имеет смысл считать заново 6! ? Нельзя хотя бы переиспользовать предыдущее значение?

Comment: Подумайте, как посчитать `(-1)**k * x**k/fact(3*k)`, если вам известно это выражение, вычисленное для `k-1`.

Comment: У вас  каждый член последовательности состоит из определенных множителей. Вот их мы можете засунуть в рекурсию, о чем вам подсказывают все комментарии выше.

Comment: @Alpensin Да, можно

Comment: @Volk  Я просто немного не понимаю как это реализовать, но спасибо за помощь

Comment: @Volk не могли бы Вы помочь мне с реализацией этой идеи?

Comment: Лучше чем @Nowhere Man  я пока не придумал. :)

Comment: @Дмитрий, был ли полезен [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1550297/386633)?

Answer (score 1):

Можно было обойтись без рекурсивного вычисления факториала, вместо этого следовало накапливать отношение `x**k/fact(3*k)` в цикле, также проще менять знак вместо вычисления `-1**k`:

```py
EPS = 1e-12

def fun(x):
    k = 0
    s = x
    p = 1
    sign = -1
    final_sum = 0
    while abs(s) > EPS:
        k += 1
        t = 3 * k  # 3, 6, 9..
        p *= x / (t * (t - 1) * (t - 2)) # в знаменателе 1*2*3; 4*5*6; 7*8*9..
        s *= sign * p
        sign *= -1
        final_sum += s
    return final_sum
```

Если *обязательно* требуется рекурсия, то код можно переписать в следующем виде:

```py
def fun2(x):
    return rec(x, 0, -1, x, 1, 3) # проинициализировать те же переменные
    
def rec(x, tot, sign, s, p, t):
    if abs(s) <= EPS:
        return tot
    p *= x / (t * (t - 1) * (t - 2))
    s *= sign * p

    return rec(x, tot + s, -sign, s, p, t + 3)
```

Тест

```py
print('цикл    : ', fun(100))
print('-----------')
print('рекурсия: ', fun2(100))
```

```
цикл    :  52190.72272214074
-----------
рекурсия:  52190.72272214074
```

---

*Дополнение* Как заметил MBo в комментарии, параметр `sign` можно убрать полностью, и код тогда упростится:

```py
EPS = 1e-12

def fun(x):
    s = x
    p = 1
    t = 3
    final_sum = 0
    while abs(s) > EPS:
        p *= -x / (t * (t - 1) * (t - 2))
        s *= p
        t += 3
        final_sum += s
    return final_sum

def fun2(x):
    return rec(x, 0, x, 1, 3)
    
def rec(x, tot, s, p, t):
    if abs(s) <= EPS:
        return tot
    p *= -x / (t * (t - 1) * (t - 2))
    s *= p
    return rec(x, tot + s, s, p, t + 3)
```

Comment: Можно избавиться от sign:   `p *= -x / (t *...`